# Multiple rows come back of same ID, just need one

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to list several products on a page. My query returns multiples of the same product and I am trying to figure out how to limit it to one only with my query.

The primary key on the first table that we will call table_one is ID. 
The second table has a column of ProductID that references the primary key on table_one.

My query brings me back multiples of my ProductID that is equal to 6 below. I just want one result to be brought back, BUT I still want my all of my data in DateReserved on table_two to be queried. Pretty sure I need to add one more thing to my query, but I have not had much luck.

The results I want back are as follows.

```
ID   Productname  Quantity              Image       Date Reserved         SumQuantity

6    productOne          6        'image.jpg'          03-31-2013                   3           
7    productTwo          1      'product.jpg'          04-04-2013                   1
```

Here is my first table. table_one

```
ID   Productname  Quantity              Image

6    productOne          6        'image.jpg'                 
7    productTwo          1      'product.jpg'
```

Here is my second table. table_two

```
ID     ProductID       DateReserved  QuantityReserved

1             6          03-31-2013                 3                 
2             6          04-07-2013                 2
3             7          04-04-2013                 1
```

Here is my query that I am trying to use.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_one` 
LEFT JOIN `table_two` 
       ON `table_one`.`ID` = `table_two`.`ProductID` 
WHERE `table_one`.`Quantity` > 0  
      OR `table_two`.`DateReserved` + INTERVAL 5 DAY <= '2013-03-27' 
ORDER BY ProductName
```

Comment: Rather than adding 5 days from the date reserved, you should be subtracting 5 days from your 'ending' date (there are potentially index usability reasons for this).  Also, you should be generally using 'exclusive upper-bounds' (`<`) when dealing with date/time/timestamps.  What do you want your results to look like?  SQL as a language is about saying what your results should look like, not how to get them.

Comment: I want my results to have 5 days + out from the date that the user specifies (e.g. 03-31-2013). I don't want to have multiples of the same record back, due to this being a listing. I want each of my results showing the name and the image.

Comment: What I meant was, given the sample data you've provided, can we get sample 'target' output for the query (ie, what you want back, not what you're currently getting).  And it doesn't matter what the user provides - you can still subtract the interval from the date they provide in the query.

Comment: I put up in my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting another answer, but as it seems my first try on it was not so good ;)

To only get one result row per reservation you need to sum them up somehow.
First I suggest you explicitly select the columns you want back in your result and don't use "*".

I suggest you try something like this:

```
SELECT
        `table_one`.`ID`, `table_one`.`Productname`, `table_one`.`Image`, `table_one`.`Quantity`,
        `table_two`.`ProductID`, SUM(`table_two`.`QuantityReserved`)
    FROM
        `table_one` 
    LEFT JOIN
        `table_two` ON `table_one`.`ID` = `table_two`.`ProductID` 
    WHERE
        `table_one`.`Quantity` > 0  
        OR `table_two`.`DateReserved` + INTERVAL 5 DAY <= '2013-03-27'
    GROUP BY `table_two`.`ProductID`
    ORDER BY ProductName
```

As you see I used "SUM" to get a combined quantity, this is called aggregation and the "GROUP BY" helps you getting rid of multiple occurences of the same ProductID.

One problem that you have now is that you will have to get the reservation date from a seperate query (well at least I am now unsure how you would get it into the same query)

Comment: That is almost right! BUT I am not getting my other products from table one that have a quantity greater then 0.

Comment: I got it! I just had to change the group by on the productID to ID from first table and not second table. Thank you so much for your help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Please note that while this may work in mySQL, the exact values encountered in non-aggregate, non-grouped columns are not definable at statement write-time; they're essentially 'random'.  (This would really only be a problem here if `DateReserved` was added to the results, the query might have a difficult time telling 'which date?' if more than one row met the requirements, as everything else is keyed uniquely off `table_one.id`.)

Comment: Sorry, I did not come back yesterday again, was afk ;)
But I am glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MySQL

```
LIMIT <NUMBER>
```

should exactly do what you want, you just insert it after your ORDER BY clause, but probably you should also add one more ordering to that, so you can be sure that you will always get the one entity that you wanted and not just some "random" entity ;)

So without further ordering your query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM `table_one` 
LEFT JOIN `table_two` ON `table_one`.`ID` = `table_two`.`ProductID` 
WHERE
    `table_one`.`Quantity` > 0
    OR `table_two`.`DateReserved` +  INTERVAL 5 DAY <= '2013-03-27'
ORDER BY ProductName
LIMIT 1
```

[here some more description about that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: I'd like to bring up all the product names only once, but with all of my DateReserved data still coming back from every record in table_two.

Comment: Ah, sorry i misunderstood you question, so then you probably want to do some aggregation on the result

Comment: Aggregation? Sorry I am new to mysql. Just trying to learn the ropes.

Comment: As far as I understand you now, you want the reservations for product 6 to be summed up in one result, so you get 2 rows back from your database one containing reservation data for product 7 and one for product 6, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.member_id,a.member_name,a.gender,a.amount,b.trip_id,b.location 
FROM tbl_member a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT trip_id, MAX(amount) as amount FROM tbl_member GROUP BY trip_id ) b ON a.trip_id= b.trip_id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_trip b ON a.trip_id=c.trip_id  
ORDER BY member_name
```

Comment: there are `table_one` & `table_two` in question, not `tbl_member` & `tbl_trip`